# Reading file content to string in .Net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I am developing an application for mobile devices with the .net compact framework 2.0. I am trying to load a file's content to a string object, but somehow I can't get it done. There is no `ReadToEnd()` method in the `System.IO.StreamReader` class. Is there another class that provides this functionality?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
{
    String line;
    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
    // the file is reached.
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }
}
string allines = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I don't know why but there is no ReadAllText method in File class. Error: 'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'ReadAllText'. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you using the new keyword? Creating an instance of File and using the static File are two different things.

Comment: I am trying to use static method as you posted.

Comment: Busy reading through msdn and found "Note: This method is new in the .NET Framework version 2.0." will update my post with another example.

Comment: Works great. One note: i had to change AppendLine method for Append method. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 41):

```
string text = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
{            
    text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Another option:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
```

https://gist.github.com/paulodiogo/9134300

Simple!

Comment: A little simpler would be wrapping your middle line in a using statement so you don't have to call `Close()` on your reader. Let the framework do all that for you.

Comment: Correct. Not only does the using call the `Close()`, but it will also call the `Dispose()`, which frees up resources.

Answer (score 7):

[`File.ReadAllText(file)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) what you're looking for?

There's also [`File.ReadAllLines(file)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) if you prefer it broken down in to an array by line.

Comment: -1: `ReadAllText` is not implemented in the .NET compact framework, which is what the question was asking.

Comment: Indeed, guess I was mistaken. However, I'm a little confused because `ReadToEnd` was missing according to OP, and yet it [exists in .net 2.0 compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader_methods%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think file.ReadAllText is supported in the compact Framework. Try using this streamreader method instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446542.aspx#netcfperf_topic039

It's a VB example, but pretty easy to translate to C#
ReadLine returns null when it has no more lines to read. You can append it to a string buffer if you want.