# How do I receive a file sent from WebClient.UploadFile()?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-headers, webclient, system.net.webexception, media-type

Since this simplistic test worked (passing a string in the body):

Server code:

```
public string PostArgsAndFile([FromBody] string value, string serialNum, string siteNum)
{
    string s = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", value, serialNum, siteNum);
    return s;
}
```

Client code:

```
private void ProcessRESTPostFileData(string uri)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var data = "=Short test...";
        var result = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", data);
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
}
```

...I then tried to take it a step further (toward what I really need to do - send a file, not a string); I changed the server code to this:

```
public string PostArgsAndFile([FromBody] byte[] value, string serialNum, string siteNum)
{
    byte[] bite = value;
    string s = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", value.ToString(), serialNum, siteNum);
    return s;
}
```

...and the client code to this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var result = client.UploadFile(uri, @"C:\MiscInWindows7\SampleXLS.csv");
}
```

...but that dies at runtime with:

*System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.*

So how can I receive a file uploaded this way? What media type do I need, and how do I specify it?

### UPDATE

As I need to ultimately send a file, or at least the contents of a file, I found [this SO Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850850/reading-file-content-to-string) and changed my code to be:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\MiscInWindows7\SampleXLS.csv"))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
    string allLines = sb.ToString();
    byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(allLines);
    byte[] responseArray = client.UploadData(uri, byteData);

    // Decode and display the response.
    MessageBox.Show("\nResponse Received.The contents of the file uploaded are:\n{0}",
        System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray));
}
```

...and although that shows me that byteData is correctly assigned to, nothing seems to be going to the server - the server's "value" property:

```
public void PostArgsAndFile([FromBody] byte[] value, string serialNum, string siteNum)
```

...is just an empty byte array when the method is called.

I tried removing the [FromBody], to no avail (no change), and changing it to [FromUri] (which I didn't think would work, but tried it on a lark) caused it to crash with a WebException.

So how do I get the server to accept/recognize/receive the byte array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

It's not passing a file per se, or literally, but it *is* passing the file's contents, and that's good enough for me. If the client *has* to create an xml file, it will just have to serialize that file into a string before sending it, like so:

CLIENT

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessRESTPostXMLFileAsStr("http://Platypus:28642/api/Platypi/PostArgsAndXMLFileAsStr?serialNum=192837465&siteNum=42");
}

private void ProcessRESTPostXMLFileAsStr(string uri)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Platypus\eXtraneousMothLepidoptera.XML"))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(line);
            }
        }
        // I don't know why the prepended equals sign is necessary, but it is
        string allLines = "=" + sb.ToString();
        var result = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", allLines);
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }            
}
```

SERVER (Web API app)

```
[Route("api/Platypi/PostArgsAndXMLFileAsStr")]
public void PostArgsAndXMLFileAsStr([FromBody] string stringifiedXML, string serialNum, string siteNum)
{
    string s = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", stringifiedXML, serialNum, siteNum);
    // Parsing the contents of the stringified XML left as an exercise to the exorcist
}
```